# Intermediate signal throw and catch event in activiti is not working

Tags: java, activiti, business-process-management

I tried to throw and catch a signal named "alert" in the following bpd as explained in activiti userguide. But I am not able to trigger the service event attached to the signal catch event.
[image]

I tried triggering the signal through java

```
runtimeService.signalEventReceived("alert");
```

but signal was not caught.
Following code ensured that there is a listener attached with process is started

```
List<Execution> executions = runtimeService.createExecutionQuery()
                  .signalEventSubscriptionName("alert")
                  .list();
```

Attaching complete bpd below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="Examples">
  <signal id="alertSignal" name="alert" activiti:scope="processInstance"></signal>
  <message id="actionOnAcceptedLR" name="actionOnAcceptedLR"></message>
  <process id="demoProcessDefinition" name="demoProcessDefinition" isExecutable="true">
<subProcess id="subprocess1" name="Sub Process">
  <startEvent id="startevent2" name="Start"></startEvent>
  <eventBasedGateway id="eventgateway1" name="Event Gateway"></eventBasedGateway>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="startevent2" targetRef="eventgateway1"></sequenceFlow>
  <intermediateCatchEvent id="messageintermediatecatchevent1" name="MessageCatchEvent">
    <messageEventDefinition messageRef="actionOnAcceptedLR"></messageEventDefinition>
  </intermediateCatchEvent>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="eventgateway1" targetRef="messageintermediatecatchevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  <intermediateCatchEvent id="timerintermediatecatchevent1" name="TimerCatchEvent">
    <timerEventDefinition>
      <timeDuration>P01D</timeDuration>
    </timerEventDefinition>
  </intermediateCatchEvent>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="eventgateway1" targetRef="timerintermediatecatchevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  <serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:expression="${processDelegate.dummy1(execution)}"></serviceTask>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="messageintermediatecatchevent1" targetRef="servicetask1"></sequenceFlow>
  <serviceTask id="servicetask2" name="Service Task" activiti:expression="${processDelegate.dummy2(execution)}"></serviceTask>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow7" sourceRef="timerintermediatecatchevent1" targetRef="servicetask2"></sequenceFlow>
  <endEvent id="endevent2" name="End"></endEvent>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow8" sourceRef="servicetask2" targetRef="endevent2"></sequenceFlow>
  <intermediateCatchEvent id="signalintermediatecatchevent1" name="SignalCatchEvent">
    <signalEventDefinition signalRef="alertSignal"></signalEventDefinition>
  </intermediateCatchEvent>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow11" sourceRef="signalintermediatecatchevent1" targetRef="servicetask3"></sequenceFlow>
  <serviceTask id="servicetask3" name="Service Task" activiti:expression="${processDelegate.dummy2(execution)}"></serviceTask>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow12" sourceRef="servicetask3" targetRef="endevent4"></sequenceFlow>
  <endEvent id="endevent4" name="End"></endEvent>
  <intermediateThrowEvent id="signalintermediatethrowevent1" name="SignalThrowEvent">
    <signalEventDefinition signalRef="alertSignal"></signalEventDefinition>
  </intermediateThrowEvent>
  <sequenceFlow id="flow13" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="signalintermediatethrowevent1"></sequenceFlow>
</subProcess>
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="subprocess1"></sequenceFlow>
<endEvent id="endevent3" name="End"></endEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="flow9" sourceRef="subprocess1" targetRef="endevent3"></sequenceFlow>
 </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_demoProcessDefinition">
<bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="demoProcessDefinition" id="BPMNPlane_demoProcessDefinition">
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="subprocess1" id="BPMNShape_subprocess1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="381.0" width="561.0" x="180.0" y="120.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startevent2" id="BPMNShape_startevent2">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="210.0" y="230.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="eventgateway1" id="BPMNShape_eventgateway1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="320.0" y="227.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="messageintermediatecatchevent1" id="BPMNShape_messageintermediatecatchevent1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="430.0" y="160.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="timerintermediatecatchevent1" id="BPMNShape_timerintermediatecatchevent1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="430.0" y="310.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="servicetask1" id="BPMNShape_servicetask1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="510.0" y="150.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="servicetask2" id="BPMNShape_servicetask2">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="510.0" y="300.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent2" id="BPMNShape_endevent2">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="660.0" y="310.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="signalintermediatecatchevent1" id="BPMNShape_signalintermediatecatchevent1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="244.0" y="388.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="servicetask3" id="BPMNShape_servicetask3">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="326.0" y="378.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent4" id="BPMNShape_endevent4">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="476.0" y="388.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="signalintermediatethrowevent1" id="BPMNShape_signalintermediatethrowevent1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="650.0" y="160.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startevent1" id="BPMNShape_startevent1">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="99.0" y="293.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent3" id="BPMNShape_endevent3">
    <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="780.0" y="290.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow2" id="BPMNEdge_flow2">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="245.0" y="247.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="320.0" y="247.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow3" id="BPMNEdge_flow3">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="340.0" y="227.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="447.0" y="195.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow4" id="BPMNEdge_flow4">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="340.0" y="267.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="447.0" y="310.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow5" id="BPMNEdge_flow5">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="465.0" y="177.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="510.0" y="177.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow7" id="BPMNEdge_flow7">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="465.0" y="327.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="510.0" y="327.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow8" id="BPMNEdge_flow8">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="615.0" y="327.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="660.0" y="327.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow11" id="BPMNEdge_flow11">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="279.0" y="405.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="326.0" y="405.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow12" id="BPMNEdge_flow12">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="431.0" y="405.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="476.0" y="405.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow13" id="BPMNEdge_flow13">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="615.0" y="177.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="650.0" y="177.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow1" id="BPMNEdge_flow1">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="134.0" y="310.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="180.0" y="310.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow9" id="BPMNEdge_flow9">
    <omgdi:waypoint x="741.0" y="310.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
    <omgdi:waypoint x="780.0" y="307.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
</bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
 </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Is there something wrong am doing here? I tried putting catch event in and out of subprocess to check if this issue is causing because of any scope issue.Still no luck. Really stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a `signal throwing event` and a `signal catching event` in same process. it doesn't make any sense, how can a process throw and catch the same event at the same time. either divide your process into **two individual process** or at least put one of them in a **sub-process**.

Answer (score 2):

Your process is per definition wrong. You have to use a signal START event inside a event sub process or a boundary event on the sub process. Intermediate catch events can't be triggered without a sequence flow. You should also use a signal end event for clarity, instead of an intermediate throw event.

Change your process model to this:

[image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" targetNamespace="Examples" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="1.4.0">
  <signal id="alertSignal" name="alert" activiti:scope="processInstance" />
  <message id="actionOnAcceptedLR" name="actionOnAcceptedLR" />
  <process id="demoProcessDefinition" name="demoProcessDefinition" isExecutable="true">
    <subProcess id="subprocess1" name="Sub Process">
      <startEvent id="startevent2" name="Start" />
      <eventBasedGateway id="eventgateway1" name="Event Gateway" />
      <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="startevent2" targetRef="eventgateway1" />
      <intermediateCatchEvent id="messageintermediatecatchevent1" name="MessageCatchEvent">
        <messageEventDefinition messageRef="actionOnAcceptedLR" />
      </intermediateCatchEvent>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="eventgateway1" targetRef="messageintermediatecatchevent1" />
      <intermediateCatchEvent id="timerintermediatecatchevent1" name="TimerCatchEvent">
        <timerEventDefinition>
          <timeDuration xsi:type="tExpression" />
        </timerEventDefinition>
      </intermediateCatchEvent>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="eventgateway1" targetRef="timerintermediatecatchevent1" />
      <serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:expression="${processDelegate.dummy1(execution)}" />
      <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="messageintermediatecatchevent1" targetRef="servicetask1" />
      <serviceTask id="servicetask2" name="Service Task" activiti:expression="${processDelegate.dummy2(execution)}" />
      <sequenceFlow id="flow7" sourceRef="timerintermediatecatchevent1" targetRef="servicetask2" />
      <endEvent id="endevent2" name="End" />
      <sequenceFlow id="flow8" sourceRef="servicetask2" targetRef="endevent2" />
      <sequenceFlow id="flow13" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="signalintermediatethrowevent1" />
      <subProcess id="Task_132bv2k" triggeredByEvent="true">
        <serviceTask id="servicetask3" name="Service Task" activiti:expression="${processDelegate.dummy2(execution)}">
          <incoming>SequenceFlow_1foxg85</incoming>
          <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1wzo371</outgoing>
        </serviceTask>
        <endEvent id="endevent4" name="End">
          <incoming>SequenceFlow_1wzo371</incoming>
        </endEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1foxg85" sourceRef="signalintermediatecatchevent1" targetRef="servicetask3" />
        <sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1wzo371" sourceRef="servicetask3" targetRef="endevent4" />
        <startEvent id="signalintermediatecatchevent1" name="SignalCatchEvent">
          <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1foxg85</outgoing>
          <signalEventDefinition />
        </startEvent>
      </subProcess>
      <endEvent id="signalintermediatethrowevent1" name="SignalThrowEvent">
        <incoming>flow13</incoming>
        <signalEventDefinition />
      </endEvent>
    </subProcess>
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start" />
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="subprocess1" />
    <endEvent id="endevent3" name="End" />
    <sequenceFlow id="flow9" sourceRef="subprocess1" targetRef="endevent3" />
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_demoProcessDefinition">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_demoProcessDefinition" bpmnElement="demoProcessDefinition">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_subprocess1" bpmnElement="subprocess1" isExpanded="true">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="117" y="100" width="696" height="529" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_startevent2" bpmnElement="startevent2">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="262" y="230" width="35" height="35" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="268" y="265" width="24" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_eventgateway1" bpmnElement="eventgateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="372" y="227" width="40" height="40" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="321" y="200" width="75" height="13" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_messageintermediatecatchevent1" bpmnElement="messageintermediatecatchevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="482" y="160" width="35" height="35" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="424" y="136" width="87" height="24" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_timerintermediatecatchevent1" bpmnElement="timerintermediatecatchevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="482" y="310" width="35" height="35" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="457" y="345" width="85" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_servicetask1" bpmnElement="servicetask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="562" y="150" width="105" height="55" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_servicetask2" bpmnElement="servicetask2">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="562" y="300" width="105" height="55" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_endevent2" bpmnElement="endevent2">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="712" y="310" width="35" height="35" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="720" y="345" width="20" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_servicetask3" bpmnElement="servicetask3">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="292" y="460" width="105" height="55" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_endevent4" bpmnElement="endevent4">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="445" y="470" width="35" height="35" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="453" y="505" width="20" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_startevent1" bpmnElement="startevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="-45" y="378" width="35" height="35" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="-39" y="413" width="24" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_endevent3" bpmnElement="endevent3">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="968" y="378" width="35" height="35" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="976" y="413" width="20" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow2" bpmnElement="flow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="297" y="247" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="372" y="247" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="335" y="222" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow3" bpmnElement="flow3">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="392" y="227" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="499" y="195" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="446" y="186" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow4" bpmnElement="flow4">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="392" y="267" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="499" y="310" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="446" y="264" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow5" bpmnElement="flow5">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="517" y="177" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="562" y="177" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="540" y="152" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow7" bpmnElement="flow7">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="517" y="327" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="562" y="327" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="540" y="302" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow8" bpmnElement="flow8">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="667" y="327" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="712" y="327" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="690" y="302" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow13" bpmnElement="flow13">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="667" y="177" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="702" y="177" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="685" y="162" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow1" bpmnElement="flow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="-10" y="395" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="117" y="395" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="54" y="380" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_flow9" bpmnElement="flow9">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="813" y="394" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="968" y="394" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="891" y="379" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="SubProcess_0vmvwx2_di" bpmnElement="Task_132bv2k" isExpanded="true">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="171" y="397" width="350" height="200" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_1foxg85_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1foxg85">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="255" y="488" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="292" y="488" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="274" y="473" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_1wzo371_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1wzo371">
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="397" y="488" />
        <omgdi:waypoint xsi:type="omgdc:Point" x="445" y="488" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="421" y="463" width="0" height="0" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="StartEvent_0cgsra4_di" bpmnElement="signalintermediatecatchevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="219" y="470" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="193" y="505" width="88" height="13" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="EndEvent_1uo4u55_di" bpmnElement="signalintermediatethrowevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds x="702" y="160" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds x="675" y="195" width="90" height="13" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```